# How in Excel to Remove only 1st comma (exact character, symbol or string)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, substitution

I have numbers witch when is 1000 then has comma "," before hundreds like 1,234,00

How to remove 1st comma or make 2nd to appear so it would be **1234,00** or in excel as it works as number if has only space then with space or comma?

I have formula so far for getting number

```
=MID(LEFT($A604;FIND(" on ";$A604)-1);FIND("?";$A604)+1;LEN($A604))*1
```

And for removing all i put it in substitute to remove commas but that makes number wrong higher like 123400

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(LEFT($A604;FIND(" on ";$A604)-1);FIND("?";$A604)+1;LEN($A604));",";"")*1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the format `#,##0`, puts a comma before every third number. You need to treat it as a string

Try this in B2:

```
    =IF(A2<999,A2,CONCATENATE(MID(A2,1,LEN(A2)-3),",",MID(A2,LEN(A2)-2,3)))
```

Depending on your use it might be best to remove the `IF`